# How to get parameter value from react-router-dom v6 in class

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v6 and don't know how to get parameter value

ex: `http://localhost:3000/user/:id`

i want to get `:id`

Someone use hook `useParams` to get but i'm using class so i can't use hook.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The library-provided HOC, withRouter, has been deprecated in React Router v6. If you need to use v6 and are using class-based React components, then you will need to write your own HOC which wraps the v6 use* hooks.

For example:

```
export function withRouter( Child ) {
  return ( props ) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return <Child { ...props } navigate={ navigate } location={ location } />;
  }
}
```

This is useful if you have a large code base that you need to move to v6, but haven't migrated all of your class-based components into functional ones.

This is based on the recommendation from the dev team as stated in this Github issue: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7256 t

Answer (score 9):

Typescript HoC

```js
import React from "react";
import { NavigateFunction, useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router";

export interface RoutedProps<Params = any, State = any> {
    location: State;
    navigate: NavigateFunction;
    params: Params;
}


export function withRouter<P extends RoutedProps>( Child: React.ComponentClass<P> ) {
    return ( props: Omit<P, keyof RoutedProps> ) => {
        const location = useLocation();
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const params = useParams();
        return <Child { ...props as P } navigate={ navigate } location={ location } params={ params }/>;
    }
}
```

then let the class component props extends RoutedProps with optional Params and State types

Comment: Shouldn't `location` be of type `Location` (as exported from `react-router`) and `params` of type `URLSearchParams`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-redux, this example will help you. 
where you are defining your Routes, Use that component as shown:

```
            <Route path="/user" component={ManageUser} />
            <Route path="/user/:id" component={ManageUser} />
```

In this ManageUser component, where you are doing `mapStateToProps` your can use like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
   // get the user
    const contextuser = getUserById(state.users, id);
    return {
        contextuser; contextuser
    };
}
```

In this way you can pass the User to your component.

Answer (score -2):

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

`export withRouter(YourComponent)`

then access `this.props.match.params` in your component

Comment: i'm using react-router-dom v6 and withRouter is not available: `'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: @AnDương is there a reason you need to use v6?

Comment: yes, it is very light and have Outlet is very useful

Comment: and the reason you can't use a functional component?