# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') - React Login Class

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to use a Login authentication, but i got this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push'). Im using React V6. The app is fxing on login page correctly but the error came when i get the authentication.

My RouterClass:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from './App/pages/HomePage'
import UsersPage from './App/pages/UsersPage'
import Login from './App/pages/Login'
import PrivateOutlet from './Auth'


function RoutesController() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />

                <Route
                    path="/home"
                    element={<PrivateOutlet />}
                >
                    <Route path="" element={<HomePage />} />
                </Route>

                <Route
                    path="/user"
                    element={<PrivateOutlet />}
                >
                    <Route path="" element={<UsersPage />} />
                </Route>

                <Route path="*" element={<h1>NOT FOUND</h1>} />

            </Routes>
        </Router>
    )

}
```

My Login Index page (i've tried to use useNavigate, but doesn't work):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Wrapper from "../../../components/Wrapper";
import "./style.css"
import logo from "../../../assets/icons/logotipo_semfundo.png"
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { MdEmail, MdLock } from "react-icons/md"
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

// function Navi(path){
//     const navigate = useNavigate()
//     navigate(path, { replace: true })
// }


class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        console.log(props)
        super(props)
        this.state= {
            message: '',
        }
    }   


    signIn = async event => {        
        const data = {email: this.email, password: this.password}        

        const requestInfo = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }),
        }

        fetch('api-link', requestInfo).then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json()
            }
            throw new Error('Login Inválido...')
        }).then(token => {
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token)
            this.props.history.push({pathname: '/home'})
            // Navi("/home")            
            return                       
            
        }).catch(e => (this.setState({message: e.message})))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Wrapper className="login">
                <Wrapper className="login-img">
                    <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
                </Wrapper>

                <Wrapper className="login-form">
                    <h1 className="h1" >Login</h1>
                    {
                        this.state.message !== '' ? (
                            <span color="black">{this.state.message}</span>
                        ): ''
                    }
                    <form id="loginForm">
                        <Wrapper>
                            <Wrapper>
                                <MdEmail />
                                <input 
                                    id="email" 
                                    type="text" 
                                    name="email" 
                                    placeholder="Digite um E-mail"
                                    onChange={e => this.email = e.target.value}
                                ></input>
                            </Wrapper>
                            <Wrapper>
                                <MdLock />
                                <input 
                                    id="password" 
                                    type="password" 
                                    name="password" 
                                    placeholder="Senha"
                                    onChange={e => this.password = e.target.value}
                                ></input>
                            </Wrapper>
                            <Wrapper>                                
                                <Button
                                    // label="Submit"
                                    // type="submit"
                                    // form="loginForm"
                                    onClick={this.signIn}
                                    block="true"   
                                    color="primary"                               
                                >
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </Wrapper>
                        </Wrapper>
                    </form>
                </Wrapper>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

My Auth Page:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const isAuth = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken') !== null) {    
        console.log("AUX", localStorage.getItem('accessToken'))
        return false
    } 
    return true 
}

const PrivateOutlet = () => {
    return (
        isAuth() ? <Outlet />
            : <Navigate
                to={{
                    pathname: '/',
                    state: { message: 'Usuário não autorizado' }
                }}
            />
    )
}

export default PrivateOutlet
```

Meu package Packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "pingpong-dashboardadmin",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365009/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-react-router-dom-v6-in-class
create an HOC as in this. add history also in the answer. and create history with useHistory

Answer (score 0):

you can pass props, like this,
so it will now have access to props with history in it

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Login {...this.props}/>} />
```

Comment: Like this (get the same error)? function RoutesController(props) {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Login {...props}/>} />