# How do I pass a URL Param to a selector

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, reselect, mapstatetoprops

I recive a url param from `useParams`. I want to pass it to a selector using `mapStateToProps`.

collection.component.jsx

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { selectShopCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selectors";

import './collection.styles.scss'

const Collection = ({ collection }) => {
  const { collectionId } = useParams();
  console.log(collection)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{collection}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collection: selectShopCollection(ownProps.match.params.collectionId)(state)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Collection);
```

shop.selectors.js

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect"

const selectShop = state => state.shop

export const selectShopCollections = createSelector([selectShop], shop =>
  shop.collections
)

export const selectShopCollection = collectionUrlParam =>
  createSelector([selectShopCollections], collections =>
    collections.find(collection => collection.id === collectionUrlParam)
  )
```

I guess the problem is that, I cannot pass params using match as react-router-dom v6 does not pass it in props. Is there any other way to pass `collectionId` to the selector `selectShopCollection`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Collection` is a function component I suggest importing the `useSelector` hook from `react-redux` so you can pass the `collectionId` match param directly. It simplifies the component API. `reselect` selectors work well with the `useSelector` hook.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { selectShopCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selectors";
import './collection.styles.scss'

const Collection = () => {
  const { collectionId } = useParams();
  const collection = useSelector(selectShopCollection(collectionId));

  console.log(collection);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{collection}</h1>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection component can be given props by `withRouter`. But it was deprecated with react-router v6. Hence we need to create our own HOC which wrap our component.
I created a HOC like this:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const params = useParams()

  return (
    <WrappedComponent {...props} params={params} />
  )
}

export default withRouter;
```

See this answer for [How to get parameter value from react-router-dom v6 in class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62877124) to see why this HOC was made.

And, we can import the `withRouter` to the component and use with `connect` inside `compose`. Read more on [compose](https://redux.js.org/api/compose/). It just returns final function obtained by composing the given functions from right to left.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  collection: selectShopCollection(ownProps.params.collectionId)(state)
})

export default compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps))(Collection)
```